# AJAX, Django and HTML Select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a form with many fields, but I have two selects, one for select the country and one for select the cities of the country that I selected.

I want to make this: When I choose the country in the first select I want to change the cities of the second select filtered by the id of the contry that I selected.

Here is my Models.py

```
class country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class country_cities(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    country = models.ForeignKey(country)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

And Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <select name="country" onchange="listCities()">
    {% for country in countrylist %}
      <option value="{{ country.id }}">{{ country.country_name }}</option>
    {% endor %}
  </select>
  <select name="city" id="citylist">
    <!--HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LIST JUST THE CITIES OF THE COUNTRY THAT I SELECTED-->

  </select>
</form>
```

How do I make my view and what libraries I have to import in my views.py? Also I'm not sure if my AJAX library or my script is correct.

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function listCities()
  {
    var countryid = $("[name='country']").val();
    $('#citylist').html('');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "countryid="+countryid,
      url: "editprofile/",
      success: function(result)
      {
        var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
        var dataHandler = $("#citylist");
        $.each(resultObj, function(key, val)
        {
            var newRow = $('<option value="'+val.id+'">');
            newRow.html(' '+val.city_name +'');
            dataHandler.append(newRow);
        });

      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of doing an Ajax call, have you considered having all of your cities loaded client side in a json object and using plain javascript to change the options in your second select?

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q4np1169/ of how that would look. (using jquery, not plain js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `getJSON` instead of `POST` for something similar. This assumes that you take out `onchange` from HTML and use `change` within jQuery instead, with a `select` box ID of `#countrylist`. It uses the value from the select box as the lookup `id` for country.

You'll need a `view` for the ajax call, too. The `url` variable in the AJAX portion will hook to that. Your `views.py` and `script.js` could have something like this:

```
#views.py
#...other imports...
from django.core import seralizers

def select_country(request):
  if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
    selected_country = request.GET.get('id')
    json_city = serializers.serialize("json", country_cities.objects.filter(country_id = selected_country))
    return HttpResponse(json_city, content_type='application/json')
  else:
    return HttpResponse("no-go")

#YourScript.js
$(function(){
//...your AJAX configurations would go up here, like CSRF stuff...

$(document).on('change', "#countrylist", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).val());
    var url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/yourURLtoView
    $.getJSON(url, {id: $(this).val()}, function(j) {
        var options = '<option value="">---??---</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + parseInt(j[i].pk) + '">' + j[i].fields['city_name'] + '</option>';
        }
        console.log(options); //This should show the new listing of filtered options.
        $("#citylist").html(options);
        $("#citylist option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    $("#countrylist").attr('selected', 'selected');
});

});
```

Also, if I might recommend that you rename your `country_cities` model to just `City`. Imagine classes as a proper Entity, like `Car` or `Person` or `Computer`. Let me know if this works for you, as I tried to transcribe it from one of my own files.